# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type--By Kevin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I got an old problem but I couldn't find correct answer here .

Can any body tell me the answer?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MvcApplication1.Models;



public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //return View();
        var maintableToEdit = (from m in _DB.mainTable where m.Id = id select m).First();

        return View(maintableToEdit);


    }
```

Error   1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\localhost\MvcApplication1\Controllers\HomeController.cs    80  60  MvcApplication1

Error   3   'MvcApplication1.Models.mainTable' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.mainTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\localhost\MvcApplication1\Controllers\HomeController.cs    81  68  MvcApplication1

Thank s a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [equality (`==`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) operator instead of [assignment (`=`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx):

```
var maintableToEdit = (from m in _DB.mainTable where m.Id == id select m).First();
```

Or for brevity:

```
var maintableToEdit = _DB.mainTable.First(m => m.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` (equality operator) instead of `=` (assignment operator).